# How do I use jQuery to select all children except a filter element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a main div. I'd like to select all in the main div, except the start div and it's all children element(as blew code, pink block).

.filter() ==> it shows the all children element of star div.

.not()==> it shows the star div,expect the input and button element.

```js
$("*.main,.main *").filter("*.start,.start *").css({
  "backgroundColor": "pink"
});


$("*.main,.main *").filter("*.start,.start *").click((e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert("filter")
});
```

```css
.main,
.main * {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.start,
.start * {
  color: pink;
  border: 2px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:500px;" class="main">(main)
  <div class="parent">div (parent)
    <div class="start">start
      <form id="more_form" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
        <button id="more">Send my greetings</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>div </div>
    <div>div </div>
    <div>div </div>
    <div>div </div>
  </div>

  <p>In this exampl".</p>
</div>
```

As result,when I click star div,it shows alert,too.

I expect when click the non-pink block trigger the function , 
how can I do?thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click on `main` and check the target of the event to see if it is start or within start by using `closest()`

```js
$("*.main,.main *").filter("*.start,.start *").css({
  "backgroundColor": "pink"
});

$('.main').click((e) => {
  if (!$(e.target).closest('.start').length) {
    alert("filter")
  }
});
```

```css
.main,
.main * {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.start,
.start * {
  color: pink;
  border: 2px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:500px;" class="main">(main)
  <div class="parent">div (parent)
    <div class="start">start
      <form id="more_form" method="get" onsubmit="return false;">FORM
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
        <button id="more">Send my greetings</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>div </div>
    <div>div </div>
    <div>div </div>
    <div>div </div>
  </div>

  <p>In this exampl".</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("*.main,.main *").filter("*.start,.start *").css({"backgroundColor": "pink"});
   
    // Remove the wildcard after main because it will access all the class after it
     $("*.main,.main").click((e)=>{
         e.stopPropagation();
         alert("filter")
     });
     $(".start").click((e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
     });
```

```css
.main, .main * {
            display: block;
            border: 2px solid lightgrey;
            color: lightgrey;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 15px;
  }

.start,.start * {
            color: pink;
            border: 2px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:500px;" class="main">(main)
        <div class="parent">div (parent)
            <div class="start">start
                <form  id="more_form" method="get">
                    <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
                    <button id="more">Send my greetings</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>div </div>
            <div>div </div>
            <div>div </div>
            <div>div </div>
        </div>

        <p>In this exampl".</p>
    </div>
```